# Linker error with PyList_New

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, macos

I was trying to use C-function in python script when I faced with this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyList_Append", referenced from:
      _count_arr in mi1-5e9b85.o
  "_PyList_New", referenced from:
      _count_arr in mi1-5e9b85.o
  "_Py_BuildValue", referenced from:
      _count_arr in mi1-5e9b85.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

.cpp file is:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
//#include <Python.h>
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m/Python.h"
#include <vector>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" PyObject* count_arr(char** arr, unsigned n2, char* word)
#else
PyObject* count_arr(char** arr, unsigned n2, char* word)
#endif
{
    PyObject * PList = PyList_New(0);
    vector <int> intVector;
    for(unsigned j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    {
        if(strstr(arr[j], word) != NULL) {intVector.push_back(j);}
    }
    vector<int>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = intVector.begin(); it != intVector.end() ; it++ )
    {
        PyList_Append(PList, Py_BuildValue("i", *it));
    }
    return PList;
}
```

If I try to include Python.h, I get message about absence of this header. Operating system is macos.

Comment: You need to include Python.h. If this is giving you an error, you need to pass a `-I` with the path to the Python headers. And you also need to pass the Python library to the linker with a `-l`, and if that gives you an error, you also need a `-L` with the path to the Python libs. This should all be explained in the Embedding and Extending docs, but it also requires some basic knowledge of C++ and using clang that you may also be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer: if you use clang, you need to pass something like

```
clang mi.o -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include -lpython3.6 -L /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib
```

However, if you use g++, you need to use command

```
g++ -fPIC -c mi1.cpp -o mi.o -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m/
g++ -shared -lpython3.6 -L /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib -olibmi.so mi.o
```